# Spring test properties file overriden by main properties file

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jpa, configuration

I have a project where I am setting up Spring test configuration, for the DAO (JPA) layer. My test config gets loaded but only after the main config, especially properties file. So instead of trying to connect to HSQLDB, my test connects to the "real" PostGre database.

Here is my test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"/spring-dao-test.xml"})
@Transactional
@Rollback
public class EnseigneDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    EnseigneDao enseigneDao;

    public EnseigneDaoTest() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindById() {
        Enseigne enseigne = enseigneDao.findById(Enseigne.class, "4");

        assertNotNull(enseigne);
        assertEquals("Auchan should have ID 4", "Auchan", enseigne.getLibelle());
    }
}
```

Here is the spring-dao-test.xml :

```
<!-- Searches for entities in this package, no need for Persistence.xml -->
<context:component-scan base-package="fr.xxx.ddc.dao" />

<context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:fr/insee/config/ddc-dao-test.properties"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="fr.xxx.ddc.model" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${fr.xxx.ddc.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">${fr.xxx.ddc.hibernate.max_fetch_depth}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">${fr.xxx.ddc.hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="HSQL"/>
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${fr.xxx.database.ddc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${fr.xxx.database.ddc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${fr.xxx.database.ddc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${fr.xxx.database.ddc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

The ddc-dao-test.properties :

```
fr.xxx.ddc.hibernate.schema=ddc
fr.xxx.ddc.hibernate.max_fetch_depth=3
fr.xxx.ddc.hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size=15
fr.xxx.ddc.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
fr.xxx.ddc.hibernate.show_sql=false

#Driver H2 pour test
fr.xxx.database.ddc.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.Driver

fr.xxx.database.ddc.url=hsqldb:mem:
fr.xxx.database.ddc.username=sa
fr.xxx.database.ddc.password=
```

and I get the following log :

```
09:24:40.262 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [class path resource [fr/insee/config/ddc-dao.properties]] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
[...]
09:24:41.717 [main] INFO org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [fr/insee/config/ddc-dao-test.properties]
09:24:41.718 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [localProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
09:24:41.719 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'fr.xxx.ddc.hibernate.max_fetch_depth' in [environmentProperties]
09:24:41.719 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'fr.xxx.ddc.hibernate.max_fetch_depth' in [systemProperties]
09:24:41.720 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'fr.xxx.ddc.hibernate.max_fetch_depth' in [systemEnvironment]
09:24:41.720 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'fr.xxx.ddc.hibernate.max_fetch_depth' in [class path resource [fr/insee/config/ddc-dao.properties]]
09:24:41.720 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'fr.xxx.ddc.hibernate.max_fetch_depth' in [class path resource [fr/insee/config/ddc-dao.properties]] with type [String] and value '3'
09:24:41.721 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'fr.xxx.ddc.hibernate.max_fetch_depth' in [environmentProperties] with type [String] and value '3'
```

How do I get rid of the ddc-dao.properties ? It seems there are some concepts I didn't get.
Thanks in advance.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are hard coding the path to the properties file. Instead use `@PropertySource` on your test (and config class outside the test) to acess the correct properties.

Comment: @dambros : I removed  
<context:property-placeholder -->
        location="classpath:fr/insee/config/ddc-dao-test.properties"/>
in Web.xml and added 
@PropertySource({"/ddc-dao-test.properties"})
in EnseigneDaoTest.
ddc-dao-test is not loaded, and I get
    nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [${fr.insee.database.ddc.driverClassName}]

Comment: It should be `@PropertySource("classpath:ddc-dao-test.properties")`.

Comment: The problem was
<context:component-scan base-package="fr.insee.ddc.dao" />
This was loading the main application config, which loaded every Java config including the main one. No need for @PropertyResource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to do it.
The problem is indeed the

```
<context:component-scan base-package="fr.xxx.ddc.dao" />
```

loading DaoConfiguration.java, itself loading the main .properties file.
I needed to exclude the class, which is done this way :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="fr.xxx.ddc.dao" >
    <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="fr.xxx.ddc.dao.config.DaoConfiguration"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

and then my DaoConfiguration is no more loaded, nor the ddc-dao-config.xml or the ddc-dao.properties. My in-memory db is used as the log shows :

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "ENSEIGNES" not found
```

Hope this helps someone.